# Linux C: Synchronize main process with multiple other processes on read from shared memory

Tags: c, synchronization, shared-memory

I have a main process which allocates shared memory and then creates multiple processes (each running the same program). These processes write status updates every 2 seconds to specific areas of the shared memory (this means each process has its own memory area, so no synch. between write accesses necessary).

The main process then runs through the shared memory, combining the single status updates to a complete one (also every two seconds).

I have up two 30 processes running and sometimes the complete values I am getting don't match up with the two second timeframe (probably because some processes were not able to precisely write their data out every 2s).

Because of this, I only want to write the complete status update to console in case each process has updated its values.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: *probably because some processes were not able to precisely write their data out every 2s*  Or your main process reads an incomplete update because it's reading the data when it's in the middle of being updated.  Unless the data is shared as an atomic type suitable to be shared between processes, you still need to synchronize between the writer and the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, out of many possible approaches, is to use atomic operations to create a global (read) lock and a "write" semaphore / counter.

For example, in the beginning of the shared memory you might use the following struct:

```
/* supports up to 255 parallel processes. Use uint16_t for more. */
struct { _Atomic uint8_t writing_counter; _Atomic uint8_t lock; } sync_ = {0};
```

Each update would look something like this (pseudo-code):

```
_Atomic uint16_t lock = atomic_xchange(&sync_.lock, 1);
if(lock){
   goto reschedule;       /* reschedule the update attempt */
}
atomic_fetch_add(&sync_.writing_counter, 1); /* increase writing counter */
atomic_xor_fetch(&sync_.lock, 1); /* release lock */
/* update */
/* ... */
atomic_fetch_sub(&sync_.writing_counter, 1); /* decrease writing counter */
```

The master process will need to manage to both lock the global lock and make sure there's no other process writing data.

```
_Atomic uint16_t lock = atomic_xchange(&sync_.lock, 1);
if(lock){
   goto reschedule;                  /* reschedule the update attempt */
}
if(atomic_load(&sync_.writing_counter)){
   atomic_xor_fetch(&sync_.lock, 1); /* unlock before rescheduling */
   goto reschedule;                  /* reschedule the update attempt */
}
/* collect data (be quick, because this is a critical section) */
/* ... */
atomic_xor_fetch(&sync_.lock, 1); /* release lock */
```

Then again, there are many other ways to do this. It's really up to what you really need.